# Wowza and Adobe Stratus/Cirrus

Tags: wowza, adobe-cirrus, soundcloud-stratus

We have one website where we stream live sport events over (Wowza media server).

Wowza dont support p2p now.

Is possible to integrate wowza with Adobe Stratus/Cirrus?

Any player example?

Answer (score 0):

Im using Adobe Cirrus with wowza in chatroullete project.
Flash client has 2 NetConnactions. First connection connected to wowza. Second - connected to Cirrus. 
After flash app connected to cirrus it send NetConnection.nearID to wowza. So if I need connect one flash app instance with another I can get client's nearID from wowza